# Calculate total price on checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a registration form where you can select different items and their price is supposed to add up and go in the `Price` input. The only thing that doesn't work properly is the calculations.

If you select 1 checkbox it adds up, but when you add 1 more it doesn't calculate.
I am not sure if I used `toFixed()` correctly. Does anybody know what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

**The other thing is:**
When you select a checkbox, the extraoption slelect with that id should be required. that works, but it makes all the selects required. I am not sure why since i put the "id_number" with the "extraoptions" If anybody could help me out, that would be very much appreciated!

```html
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control price" data-blocked="<>{}" value="{{ ($cache['price'] ?? old('price') ?? $registration->isg_price ?? $distance_price) }}" readonly>

<!-- foreach to get the extra options and the extras, because they come from another table -->
<label>options</label><br>

@foreach($option_array as $option)  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" id="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" value="{{ $option->exa_id }}" {{ isset($cache) ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')  : (old() ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '') : ($registration ? (in_array($option->exa_id, $registration_options) ? 'checked' : '') : '')) }} >
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_price }}" class="option_price_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
    <label>{{ $option->exa_name }}</label> 
    <label class="exa_price">€{{ $option->exa_price }}</label>  
  </div>
  <select name="extraoptions_{{ $option->exa_id }}" class="form-control extraoptions" id="extraoptions_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($option->extraoptions as $extraoption)
      <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}" {{ ($registration ? (in_array($extraoption->eos_id, $registration_options_extra) ? 'selected' : '') : '') }}>{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  <br>
@endforeach
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  set_options();
  $(".option").change(function() {
    set_options();
  });
});

function set_options() {
  // participant is also a value we have to add up. (this works)
  var total_price = parseFloat($("#participant").val());

  $(".option").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // we take the id of the options
    var id_number = id.split("_")[1];
    var option_price = parseFloat($(".option_price_" + id_number).val());

    if (this.checked) {
      //the calculation
      total_price = parseFloat(total_price + option_price).toFixed(2);
      $("#extraoptions_" + id_number).attr('required', 'True');
    } else {
      $("#extraoptions_" + id_number).attr('required', 'False');
    }
  });

  parseFloat($("#price").val(total_price)).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I do need to use the id's i think because of the select options. there are different options where the id's aren't the same. also i tried replacing = with +=-, but then it doesnt add up

Comment: You don't need the `id`. I've added an example without them below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that calling `toFixed()` on `total_price` sets it to a string. Therefore in the next loop you're actually *concatenating* a value to the string instead of *adding* a numerical value. To fix that, only call `toFixed()` at the point you display the value in the UI.

That being said there are several things you can do to improve the code. Firstly, don't use dynamic ids, and certainly don't slice them up using string manipulation to pull out parts you need, or relate elements to each other. To do that use common classes and DOM traversal instead, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $options = $(".option").change(function() {
    var total_price = parseFloat($("#participant").val());

    $options.each(function() {
      var option_price = parseFloat($(this).next('.option_price').val());
      $(this).closest('div').next('.extraoptions').prop('required', this.checked);
      if (this.checked)
        total_price += option_price;
    });

    $("#price").val(total_price.toFixed(2));
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
@foreach($option_array as $option)  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" value="{{ $option->exa_id }}" {{ isset($cache) ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')  : (old() ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '') : ($registration ? (in_array($option->exa_id, $registration_options) ? 'checked' : '') : '')) }} >
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_price }}" class="option_price">
    <label>{{ $option->exa_name }}</label> 
    <label class="exa_price">€{{ $option->exa_price }}</label>  
  </div>
  <select name="extraoptions_{{ $option->exa_id }}" class="form-control extraoptions">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($option->extraoptions as $extraoption)
      <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}" {{ ($registration ? (in_array($extraoption->eos_id, $registration_options_extra) ? 'selected' : '') : '') }}>{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! i changed some toFixed() and the calculations now work, but every select still gets required then i check 1 checkbox. i dont know why because i use "#extraoptions_ + id_number"